# interpretation of tangent space of level curve manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ a smooth function, $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$ a regular value, define the manifold $M_c = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n| f(x) =c\}$. Then we get that the tangent space at every point $x \in M$ has tangent space of dimension $n-m$. So fix a point $x$ and look at $T_x M_c$, the tangent space at $x$, since $f|M_c$ is a constant function in $C^\infty(M_c)$, we get that for any $v \in T_x(M_c)$, $v(f)=0$, which leads to the conclusion that $D_xf(v) = 0$, so $T_x M_c = Ker(D_xf)$.

Now I have trouble with the step that $v(f)=0$ implies $D_xf(v)=0$. If I think of the tangent vectors as directional derivatives at $x$, then it makes sense that every directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ equals $0$ implies that the differential itself is $0$. However, I cannot interpret this result if I think of $f$ as smooth map between manifolds, and $D_xf$ takes tangent space of $x$ to tangent space of $f(x)$.

Comment: What you've argued is that $T_xM_c \subset \ker(D_xf)$. You need to use the definition of regular value to finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

As you said so yourself, the tangent vectors can be interpreted as directional derivatives of $f$.

So in particular, if $\forall v \in T_xM: v(f) = 0$, then the directional derivatives of $f$ in any direction $v$ will be $0$, so $D_x f(v) = 0$.

Alternatively, since you're in Euclidean speace, you can work in local coordinates. $v(f)$ can be expressed as $\partial_v f = (D_x f)v$ (if you're not clear on why this is so let me know I'll explain more)

Comment: Writing $\times$ is *very* misleading here.

Comment: You're right, my bad